# Define co-ocurrence matrix in python using Numpy (NOT PANDAS)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, nlp

Probably this is easier than I think but I am having a hard time doing this.  I have to define a co-ocurrence matrix of words in a sentence based on a word window using Numpy arrays (not pandas df).
e.g. Given the two sentences:
["All that glitters is not gold","All that I want is You"] with window size of 4.

"All" will co-occur with nothing at te left  and with  "that", "glitters", "is", and "not" in the right for the first sentence. In such a case I should add +1 in the matrix for the values where "All" and ["that","glitters","is" and "not"] .  We do the same for all word in first sentence using a window of 4 o the left and 4 to the right. Then, in second sentence, "All" co-occur with ["that", "I", "want", "is"]. We should add again +1 to all the values, noticing that the "that" already has a value of 1 for last sentence, so now it will update to two

So lets say in this example "All" represents the 0th column and 0th row, "that" represents the first column and first row etc... such that array[0,4] = array[4,0]. So, with a window of 4 words, "All" co-occur with 4 words in first sentence (because it has nothing at the left) and we should sum +1 to array[0,1], array[0,2], array[0,3] and array[0,4]. "All" co-occur with 4 words in the second sentence( because it has nothing at left too), and we should sum +1 to array[0,1], array[0,6], array[0,7], array[0,3]

The order for the following rows/columns is therefore:

[All, that, glitters , is , not , gold, I, want, You] (only unique words in the matrix), #so the diagonal of the matrix would be 0 unless the same word is the center/focus word and is also in its window repeated.

Updating the values for "All" would look like this:

[All, that, glitters , is , not , gold, I, want, You]

array([

All         [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

that        [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

glitters    [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

is          [2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

not.        [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

gold.       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

I.          [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

want.       [1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

You.        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],

])

I shall do the same for every value using NUMPY arrays (not pandas)

I am having a very hard time defining the window and looping (how to define the values where there is only two words for the right but not 4 (the whole window). also, With pandas, as each column has already name defined, that would help me make the sums, but in numpy i am not sure on how to correctly define my loops or my matrix to do this and maintain logic in the row/column pair for each word. Please help me to understand the mechanics :(. I actually now how to do the rest of my HW, but this is the second part of it and i cant go forward with out it .